# SQL Server 2012 using SELECT in trigger breaks table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, triggers, sql-server-2012

So let me first admit that I am a SQL Server newbie.

Here's the deal: I'm trying to create a trigger on a table in SQL Server 2012, and whenever I try any kind of `SELECT` statement in the trigger, the table quits working (as in NOTHING can be inserted until the trigger is deleted). As soon as I drop the trigger, everything starts working again. If I don't do any `SELECT`s, everything is peachy. Is there a permission or something somewhere that I'm missing?

Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sometrigger
ON sometable
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM inserted
END
GO
```

Command completes successfully, but the table becomes frozen as described above.

```
CREATE TRIGGER sometrigger
ON sometable
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients = N'someaddress@somedomain.com',
    @subject = 'test',
    @body = 'test body',
    @profile_name = 'someprofile'
END
GO
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Why would you do `select *` from a trigger?  Who would get to see the result set?

Comment: How are you attempting the inserts where it "quits working"? Is it from something that is hiding exceptions/error messages?

Comment: @Andomar I wouldn't, that's just a quick example to elaborate on my problem.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The inserts are coming from a system that is using the DB as an event log. I am generating them simply by logging in/out of that system or anything else that would add an event to the table.  There are no errors displaying on that system.

Comment: Try crafting an `INSERT` statement yourself and running it in query analyzer, to see whether there are error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You're may be falling foul of the [**disallow results from triggers**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186337.aspx) option being set to 1, as it should be.

Note the warning on that page:

> This feature will be removed in the next version of Microsoft SQL Server. Do not use this feature in new development work, and modify applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible. We recommend that you set this value to 1.

I suspect that wherever you're running your inserts from is hiding an error message or exception, since you should get:

> Msg 524, Level 16, State 1, Procedure , Line
>
> "A trigger returned a resultset and the server option 'disallow_results_from_triggers' is true."

---

Or, in the alternative, you're working with a database layer that wraps all inserts in a transaction and will roll the transaction back if anything unexpected happens - such as receiving a result set or even just an extra information message saying `(x rows affected)`.

But all of this is dancing around the main issue - you shouldn't be issuing a select that attempts to return results from inside of a trigger. I might have been able to offer more help if you'd actually told us what you're trying to achieve.

If it's the second case, and it's something tripping over the `(x rows affected)` messages, that can be cured by placing `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of the trigger.

Comment: OK, I'm trying to generate email notifications of errors on a system that doesn't have any error reporting.  The only thing I have been able to think of is having a trigger that checks the severity level of the event just added to the DB and sends a email when a severity level 'ERROR' shows up.

Comment: The disallow results option is set to 0, and I have `SET NOCOUNT ON` already. I'm just trying to pull a few values from the `inserted` table, assign them to variables, and send them in an email. ex: `DECLARE @EventID int ... SELECT @EventID = [EventID] FROM inserted ... EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail ... @body = @EventID`.  How can I do that without returning results??

Comment: @Bodacious: In SQL Server, using SELECT to retrieve rows is somewhat different from using it to assign variables, to the degree that SQL Server doesn't allow mixing these two. So my question is, have you actually tried `SELECT @EventID = [EventID] FROM ...`, i.e. the *variable assignment* syntax, as opposed to just `SELECT [EventID] FROM ...` or any other kind of *data retrieval* syntax? Also, have you tried using using `inserted` as a filter only, in a join, and reading the data from the actual table (the target of the insert) instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should never return data from a trigger anyway, mainly for simplicity and maintenance reasons. It's confusing: I did an INSERT but get a resultset back.

If you need to get the values you just inserted, you'd [use the OUTPUT clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
INSERT sometable (...)
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
VALUES (...);
```

This at least tells you that the INSERT gives results.

And it is nestable too as per, say, [SQL Server concurrent transaction issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501813/sql-server-concurrent-transaction-issue/8502010#8502010)